# How to dequantify units in mathematica?

Tags: units

Is there a function which applied to a quantity returns its numerical value so I for instance can fill it into my `Predictorfunction`?

Comment: you maybe want to accept an answer to this

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Oops - found it! `QuantityMagnitude[quantity]` does the job. For example,

```
In[1]:= QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[1, "Feet"]]

Out[1]= 1
```

Comment: If you want to remove the units in an expression regardless of what level that unit resides on, you can tack `/. Quantity :> Composition[QuantityMagnitude, Quantity]` (`/. Quantity :> QuantityMagnitude@*Quantity` in version 10) or `/. Quantity[x_, y_] :> x` to the end of your expression. [Examples](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DQFCM.png).

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned, the function you're looking for is [`QuantityMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude). However, I think single argument [`QuantityMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude) is error prone. It is much better to give it a second argument:

```
QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[1, "Feet"]]
QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[1, "Feet"], "Meters"]
QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[1, "Feet"], "Seconds"]
```

> 1
>
> 381/1250
>
> Quantity::compat: Feet and Seconds are incompatible units
>
> QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[1, "Feet"], "Seconds"]

Answer (score 4):

To temporary disable Quantity for all of your functions,

`SetSystemOptions["DataOptions" -> "ReturnQuantities" -> False];`

```
In[5]:= DateDifference[DateList[{2017, 11, 11}], DateList[]]
Out[5]= Quantity[-21.5912, "Days"]
In[6]:= oldSystemOptions = SystemOptions["DataOptions"]; 
        SetSystemOptions["DataOptions" -> "ReturnQuantities" -> False];
In[7]:= DateDifference[DateList[{2017, 11, 11}], DateList[]]
Out[7]= -21.5908
```

This is a neat trick to use. This works on Mathematica 10 & 11. Or simply use `First`.

```
In[12]:= First@DateDifference[DateList[{2017, 11, 11}], DateList[]]
Out[12]= -21.5869
```

Comment: `First@Quantity[5,"Meters"]` and  `Quantity[5,"Meters"] // First` are the same thing. It works on Mathematica 9, 10, 11.

Answer (score 2):

`First` does work — try use `// First` after the expression to apply the `First` function such as below. But `QuantityMagnitude` is more proper so you can use either. `First` is for arrays and lists.

```
Quantity[5,"Meters"] // First
```

> `5`

```
Quantity[5,"Meters"] // QuantityMagnitude
```

> `5`